# Can I position the pop-up calendar from <af:inputDate>

Tags: java, calendar, jdeveloper

I am using  to get date input. When the Calendar pops-up, I want to move it to the left (starting from the left of screen). Is this feasible? If so, how to control that?

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the control with af:inputDate which decides the picker placement based on screen constraints and available space.

If you need more control, then you would be better off putting a [af:chooseDate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_chooseDate.html) into a [af:popup](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_popup.html) and launch it your self using [af:showPopupBehavior](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_showPopupBehavior.html) for triggerType click and aignId set the the input field. Experiment with different values of align attribute as explained in the [tag docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_showPopupBehavior.html).